# Dagger: No injectable members on class with multiple injections

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, code-injection, dagger

I am getting an error message when attempting to inject 2 modules into a class:

```
Error:(18, 8) error: No injectable members on ...SQLiteHandler.
Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by ...activity.AuthenticatorActivity 
for ...ServerHandlerModule


Error:(18, 8) error: No injectable members on ...ServerHandler.
Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by ....activity.AuthenticatorActivity 
for ...Modules.SQLiteHandlerModule
```

I am having trouble understanding this error message as the two modules don't seem to have any relation to each other. The injection was working before I added the ServerHandlerModule in but they seem to be interfering with each other when they are both injected.

SQLiteHandlerModule:

```
@Module(injects = {AuthenticatorActivity.class, MainActivity.class})
public class SQLiteHandlerModule  {

private final Context context;

public SQLiteHandlerModule(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SQLiteHandler providesSQLiteHandler(@ForApplication Context context) {
    return new SQLiteHandler(context);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@ForApplication
Context provideApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}
}
```

ServerHandlerModule:

```
@Module(injects = {AuthenticatorActivity.class})
public class ServerHandlerModule {

public ServerHandlerModule() {}

@Provides
@Singleton
ServerHandler providesServerHandler() {
    return new ServerHandler();
}
```

}

AuthenticatorActivity:

```
public class AuthenticatorActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {
@Inject
SQLiteHandler db;
@Inject
ServerHandler serverHandler;

private ObjectGraph objectGraph;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules());
    objectGraph.inject(this);
}

…

protected List<Object> getModules() {
    return Arrays.asList(new SQLiteHandlerModule(this), new ServerHandlerModule());
}
}
```

Does anyone know what I need to add to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger requires an annotation over the constructor of a class that is to be injected.

```
@Inject
public SQLiteHandler(@ForApplication Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Inject
public ServerHandler() {
}
```